# Get values from HTML only if the checked box is checked (HTML + Python script)

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I have a web page with  multiple checkboxes and the relative input values
[image]

with the following code:

```html
<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"second_checkbox\" name=\"second_checkbox\" value=\"" + Sample_ID + "\"><label for=\""+ Sample_ID + "\">"+ Sample_ID +"</label><br></td><td><select name=\"option\" id=\"option\"><option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\"></option><option value=\"=\">=</option><option value=\"!=\">!=</option><option value=\">\">></option><option value=\">=\">>=</option><option value=\"<\"><</option><option value=\"<=\"><=</option><option value=\"ilike\">contains</option></select></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"valore\" placeholder=\"value\"></td></tr>"
```

and I get the different values by using this functions:

```
filtri = request.form.getlist('second_checkbox')
simbolo = request.form.getlist('option')
valori = request.form.getlist('valore')
```

but the array "valori" takes all the empty values on the page and I want to take only the ones that are checked on the first checkbox.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the duplicate id's and names in the html. An id in html should  be unique. Using the right selection mechanism you don't need them either.

For the client side (so, within the browser) you can select all checked checkboxes using the selector `[type=checkbox]:checked`. Here's a  [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, evt => {
  console.clear();
  const allChecked = document.querySelectorAll(`[type='checkbox']:checked`);
  //                                                             ^ only checked
  if (allChecked.length) {
    return allChecked
      .forEach(cb => {
        const theRow = cb.closest(`tr`);
        console.log(`checked row (#${theRow.rowIndex + 1}) text input value: ${
          theRow.querySelector(`input[type='text']`).value || `no value`}`);
      });
  }
  return console.log(`none checked (yet)`);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="123"> 123
    </td>
    <td>
      selector here
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="value" value="row 1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="456"> 456
    </td>
    <td>
      selector here
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="value" value="row 2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="789"> 789
      <td>
        selector here
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="value" value="row 3">
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```